# Inverse element of addition and multiplication and isomorphic representation

Tags: complex-analysis

Given are $u=i+j+k$ and $v=1-i+j-k$.
Calculate the sum and the product of $u$ and $v$ and **the inverse element** of the addition and multiplication as well as **all three (isomorphic) representations**.

For inverse element, can I just take $-u,-v, \frac{1}{u}, \frac{1}{v}$? How do I find their isomorphic representations?

edit: One more question. How do I find conjugate complex of $u$ and $uv$?

Comment: A few questions: (i) Are these quaternions? (ii) Are you asking about the inverses of the sums and product? (iii) When you talk about the isomorphic representations, do you mean the images of these elements under automorphisms of the quartenion algebra? (iv) Is this really an algebra question rather than a complex analysis question? Sorry for throwing so many questions at you! :)

Comment: i) Yes, these are quaternions. ii)I am not sure. It is written inverse element of sum and multipliction. iii) I dont know. iv) ..

Comment: One nice trick for finding inverses of quaternions is to use the equivalence between quaternions and 2x2 matrices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations Then take the matrix inverses. Or simply write $(a + ib+jc+kd)(i+j+k) = 1$, expand, and solve for $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: The algebra of quaternions has an automorphism, given by a cyclic permutation of the generators: $i \mapsto j \mapsto k \mapsto i$. That is probably what is referred to in part (iii).

Comment: @KennyWong I did it like you said and got that inverse element od u is: $0 - \frac{1}{3}i - \frac{1}{3}j - \frac{1}{3}k$. Is that right?

Comment: Yeah, that looks right.